# How to kill all node processes with the exception of the one running VS Code on Windows

Tags: node.js, bash, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

I'm working with a Ubuntu box, Node, VS Code on Windows.

It's often required to manually kill processes when CTRL-C doesn't properly stop the process, or machine / VSCode has gone to sleep.

A nice solution  is to use `killall node`.

However, this also kills the VSCode window and forces a restart.

How can I kill all node processes minus the one powering VSCode without manually examining each process and finding the correct port / PID??

For instance:

```
$netstat -lntp | grep node

tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:545467         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      543457/node         
tcp6       0      0 :::1234                 :::*                    LISTEN      345654/node
```

The `tcp` connection needs to be maintained as it keeps VS CVode running, but I'd like to kill the `tcp6` connection (and any others).

I'm aware that one can find the port, process etc and then manually kill a process, but this is frustrating having to do it every time VSCode become inactive.

How can I run a command (perhaps through an NPM script) that kills all node processes except the one running VSCode?

Comment: Did you ever figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

Since `killall node` could also terminate your VSCode processes to your host machine

in order to kill the Node processes not spawn by VSCode, you could use the [ps](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html) command and pipe it to the [grep](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html) `-v` (--invert-match) to filter out the processes that match *`".vscode-server"`* string, and use [awk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html) to extract only the PIDs:

<sub>`killNode.sh`</sub>

```bash
#!/bin/bash

NodePIDs=$(ps aux | grep [n]ode | grep -v ".vscode-server" | awk '{print $2}' | sort | uniq)

for PID in $NodePIDs; do
    echo "Killing NodeJS process with PID: $PID"
    kill $PID
done

# App's NodeJS processes are now killed.  
# VSCode should still be connected to this host machine
```

Another way to kill Node processes that are bound to a specific **port**, you could use [lsof](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/lsof.8.html) like i.e:

<sub>`killNodePort.sh`</sub>

```bash
#!/bin/bash

PORT=8000
# PS, instead of hardcoding the port pass it as an environment variable  
# `PORT=8000 bash killNodePort.sh` or source it from .env file like:
# source .env   or:   source /abs/path/to-your/.env

NodePIDs=$(lsof -i tcp:"$PORT" | grep [n]ode | awk '{print $2}' | sort | uniq)

for PID in $NodePIDs; do
    echo "Killing NodeJS process PORT: $PORT with PID: $PID"
    kill $PID
done

# App's NodeJS processes on PORT $PORT are now killed.  
# Remote VSCode should still be connected to your host machine
```

take the above with a salt of curiosity and always explore the manuals for the commands you use (`man <commandName>`). I.e, if you have a specific case run i.e: `ps --help all` or `lsof --help` and adjust the above suggestions to accommodate.